# Animation with semantic ui

Tags: javascript, html, animation, web, semantic-ui

Trying to make an animation when clicking on a button, using semantic ui, a framework.
Tried the first code listed in this link => https://semantic-ui.com/modules/transition.html
But it doesn't work
Thanks in advance !

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Formulaire</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/form.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/transition.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pContainer">
        <div id="C1">
            <header id="title">
                <label id="titleDescription">Sign in</label>
            </header>
            <div id="C2">
                <form id="formulaire">
                    <input class="textForm" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username"></input>
                    <input class="textForm" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password"></input>
                    <a href="#">Forgot password or username ?</a>
                    <div class="normalDiv">
                        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Confirm"></input>
                        <input class="button" type="button" value="Cancel"></input>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/transition.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/form.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
(function(){
var bouttonConfirmer = document.querySelector(".button");
bouttonConfirmer.addEventListener("click",function(event){
    var objet = document.querySelector(".textForm");
    objet.transition('scale');
    alert("oki");
});
```

})();

Comment: Can you post the text instead of screenshots?

Comment: yes of course !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that semantic-ui requires jquery ([see docs](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/transition.html)) so I included jquery js and semantic-ui css/js.

The second problem is that `button[type=submit]` will submit the form and cause a page load. So you won't be able to see the transition. I changed the `type=button` to prevent this.

Lastly I made your `<input />` elements self closing.

```js
$("#confirm").on("click", function() {
    $('.textForm').transition('scale');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pContainer">
        <div id="C1">
            <header id="title">
                <label id="titleDescription">Sign in</label>
            </header>
            <div id="C2">
                <form id="formulaire">
                    <input class="textForm" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
                    <input class="textForm" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    <a href="#">Forgot password or username ?</a>
                    <div class="normalDiv">
                        <input class="button" type="button" value="Confirm" id="confirm" />
                        <input class="button" type="button" value="Cancel" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice ! it works like a charm thanks ! 
A question please, why did u implemented semantic.min.css and the semantic.min.js instead of transition.js ?

Comment: I have never used semantic-ui before. I was just found a CDN hosting the scripts so I could show how to fix it with a runnable snippet instead of downloading the code.